# inserting list of dicts as JSON binary into peewee model

Tags: postgresql, peewee

I have a simple list of dicts I want to insert into my LabelModel table in my postgres DB

```
l = [{'label': 'A',
  'x': 132.56338500976562,
  'y': 333.7539367675781,
  'width': 183.78598022460938,
  'height': 404.6580505371094,
  'score': 0.9848693609237671},
 {'label': 'B',
  'x': 179.97842407226562,
  'y': 367.101318359375,
  'width': 127.43386840820312,
  'height': 59.047882080078125,
  'score': 0.965998113155365},
 {'label': 'C',
  'x': 431.1368408203125,
  'y': 365.9712219238281,
  'width': 127.59616088867188,
  'height': 60.77362060546875,
  'score': 0.9622131586074829}]
```

```
class TblLabelByAI(BaseModel):
  name = pw.TextField()
  labels = BinaryJSONField()
  modified_at = pw.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

```
q = {"imagename":"testname","labels":l}
TblLabelByAI.get_or_create(**q)
```

Is there any reason I get the following:

```
ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: jsonb = record
LINE 1: ...testname') AND ("t1"."labels" = (CAST('{...
                                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Peewee: 3.14.9
Python 3.8

@coleifer - amazing work btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

```
from psycopg2.extras import Json

data = [{'x': 123, 'y': 123},{'x': 123, 'y': 123},{'x': 123, 'y': 123}]
data = Json(data)
```